# Scylla not working with docker volumes

Tags: docker, scylla

I am trying out Scylla with Docker and when I try to start a container with volumes like this:

Update: it is only when setting `-developer-mode=0` and it runs if setting `--developer-mode 1`. Just as is says somewhere in the error message. Then what is the different - performance?

```
docker run --name some-scylla -v $(pwd)/scylla:/var/lib/scylla -d scylladb/scylla --developer-mode=0
```

I get the following errors:

```
 docker logs some-scylla
running: (['/usr/lib/scylla/scylla_dev_mode_setup', '--developer-mode', '0'],)
running: (['/usr/lib/scylla/scylla_io_setup'],)
Unexpected end of /proc/mounts line `overlay / overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/4EW63UOV5QXIGGMQLID2222UKM:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/6XJRXN2HPJYCHXAGSSVWQ7LJM5:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/7RYKDGFWLSHQ5RNAQ7UIKI5D7I:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/GJCMLIFXUHTV5VL62MKFAXK4AF:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/URWQYQVXC7M5WACG5RLJXVXWKQ:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/Z7IZ43DGLAA4INFGTVAYIKM6OT:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/VH54CMJH4X3CA73VDJ63PA7SWD:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/4C7TNR7TY4F3QEOBOFCUBUJWGX:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/LNERBP5J7NDIO'
Unexpected end of /proc/mounts line `LH2VHSK2IDPTG:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/RNU5XYUHEFGGKKI2Z72VY6AFMR:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/62I7NFGNKNPMSYHM4SJOIZF3GE:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/ITSIUWLMY2ZDDWIYXHZN3OU3B5:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/NJZMNPZMNE4REV5ROKRYKALW66:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/6UZO7ISW4XSYPVRBAT2PWLDGTF:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/QHVAVYSQMYGUEE5WGGNNFBSKVF:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/EUSBWKEFMZRSXJ5OOMI7HC3B3V:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/QIJNRYNZVZ2RTON5CACSBQKSMA:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/PTQZWWDEG3ACWQMUYQ2V7QTVMS:/var/lib/do'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  open: No such file or directory
ERROR:root:/var/lib/scylla/data did not pass validation tests, it may not be on XFS and/or has limited disk space.
This is a non-supported setup, and performance is expected to be very bad.
For better performance, placing your data on XFS-formatted directories is required.
To override this error, enable developer mode as follow:
sudo /usr/lib/scylla/scylla_dev_mode_setup --developer-mode 1
failed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/docker-entrypoint.py", line 15, in <module>
    setup.io()
  File "/scyllasetup.py", line 33, in io
    self._run(['/usr/lib/scylla/scylla_io_setup'])
  File "/scyllasetup.py", line 22, in _run
    subprocess.check_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 558, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/lib/scylla/scylla_io_setup']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before starting up, Scylla does a benchmark of your existing I/O infrastructure and determines a bunch of things, like:

- what's the maximum number of concurrent requests the disk can take
- what's the performance of the filesystem for asynchronous operations

That information is then fed to Scylla's [internal disk I/O Scheduler](http://www.scylladb.com/2016/04/14/io-scheduler-1/) that is used to provide QoS between classes of request.

A lot of the benefits of Scylla - like low latency and automatic isolation between different I/O classes is predicated in a functioning I/O scheduler.

The error message that you see happens because your I/O layer did not pass the basic validation tests, as you can see in this message:

`ERROR:root:/var/lib/scylla/data did not pass validation tests, it may not be on XFS and/or has limited disk space.`

From the rest of the logs, I am supposing you are using docker's default overlay, as opposed to the recommended method of passing an external XFS-formatted disk to Scylla.

As you found out yourself, you can start the container in `developer-mode`. That means some aspects of Scylla (like described above) won't function correctly and you will not enjoy the best performance in the database.

If you are not doing any production deployment with this, and is only testing out basic queries and test apps, you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to create and passing an external XFS-formatted disk? See this if you now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690456/how-to-create-a-xfs-formatted-disk-folder

Comment: I have answered the said question. Thanks for your interest!