# How to create a XFS-formatted disk/folder

Tags: docker, scylla

I am playing around with [ScyllaDB](http://www.scylladb.com) in docker. To have ScyllaDB operate most efficient in docker production setup it needs a XFS-formatted disk.

Do you know how to create a XFS container volumes, file of disk - in Linux and MacOs?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do that is to create a partition or LVM volume, and then format it with xfs normally, using some tool like `mkfs.xfs`.

Once you are done, you can use the `-v` flag in docker to pass that to your container.